# Cloud Storage Client with Scala and Dataproc: missing libraries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run a simple spark script in a dataproc cluster, that needs to read/write to a gcs bucket using scala and the java Cloud Storage Client Libraries. The script is the following:

```
//Build.sbt
name := "trialGCS"

version :="0.0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

val sparkVersion = "3.0.1"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // Spark core libraries
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,

  "com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-storage" % "1.113.15"
)
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

```
package DEV

import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions

object TrialGCS extends App {
  import spark.implicits._
  val storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance.getService

}
```

I launch the script via terminal with the shell command:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --class DEV.TrialGCS --jars target/scala-2.12/trialgcs_2.12-0.0.1.jar --cluster <CLUSTERNAME> --region=<REGIONNAME>
```

However this produces the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/storage/Storage`.

If I include the cloudstorage jar manually, changing `--jars` in the previous command with

```
--jars target/scala-2.12/trialgcs_2.12-0.0.1.jar,google-cloud-storage-1.113.15.jar
```

the error is now `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/Service`.

So, apparently it's a matter of missing libraries.

On the other hand if I use `spark-shell --packages "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.113.15"` via ssh in the dataproc driver's vm all works perfectly.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution: to manage properly the package dependence, the google-cloud-storage library needs to be included via `--properties=spark.jars.packages=<MAVEN_COORDINATES>`, as shown in https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/manage-spark-dependencies . In my case this means

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --class DEV.TrialGCS \
--jars target/scala-2.12/trialgcs_2.12-0.0.1.jar \
--cluster <CLUSTERNAME> --region=<REGIONNAME> \
--properties=spark.jars.packages="com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.113.15"
```

When multiple maven coordinates for packages or multiple properties are necessary, it is necessary to escape the string: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping

For instance, for google-cloud-storage and kafka:

```
--properties=^#^spark.jars.packages=com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.113.15,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1,io#spark.executor.extraClassPath=org.apache.kafka_kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar#spark.driver.extraClassPath=org.apache.kafka_kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's ensured that you've the dependent jar in the driver machine, you can add the jars in the class path explicitly. You can try by the following command,

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark  \
--class DEV.TrialGCS \
--properties spark.driver.extraClassPath=<comma seperated full path of jars>,spark.jars.packages=com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.113.15 \
--cluster <CLUSTERNAME> --region=<REGIONNAME>
```

Comment: I've already found the solution to this issue. Please check my answer. spark.driver.extraClassPath is not necessary, but thanks for the help